# Copy value from one table A to table B with some filter in the same database sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, distinct, sql-insert

I have my_db in sql server latest with table A(raw data) and I want to create table B from A.

Table A

```
columA columB   columC columD                     columE
ali    paris    9003   2010-05-16 16:21:00.000    toy
ali    paris    902a   2010-05-16 16:21:00.000    toy
paul   paris
Yan    london
kris   london
kris   london
kris   london
```

table B should look like below with primary key on columA

```
columA columB
ali    paris
paul   paris
yan   london
kris   london
```

I tried to create table B with primary key and when trying insert , got error, trying update error, so I dropped and created again with no key just about same data type , I copied columA but cannot do the same with columB -->

```
INSERT INTO table B ( columA ) SELECT distinct( columA) FROM table A;
```

and get very annoying error like "invalid object name, invalid column name" with a valid script or some time, I get "The multi-part identifier "my_db.dbo.table B.columA" could not be bound"

```
INSERT INTO table B ( columB )
SELECT columB FROM [table A]
WHERE [my_db].[dbo].[table B].columA = (SELECT columA FROM dbo.table B);
```

I care more about the syntax of copying data from table A to table B in more normalized way, if someone has a clue on this type of error you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Why not insert both columns at once?

```
INSERT INTO tableB (columA, columnB)  
SELECT distinct columA, columnB FROM tableA;
```

Note that `distinct` is not a function (it is a language keyword), so it does not take parentheses.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work, now it works like a magic...thanks...maybe I needed a break. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you just want

```
insert into table_b( columnA, columnB )
  select distinct columnA, columnB
    from table_a
```